# "Главное что" как-либо обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация

> Мы в очередной раз забыли, что кварталы Рима – это понятие обширное и
>   главное что непредсказуемое.

"Что" хочу сохранить, а оно мне мешает выделить "главное".

Ооо... Запятую?

*...это понятие обширное и главное, что непредсказуемое.*

Ну и получилось: обширное и главное... 8-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:

*Мы в очередной раз забыли, что кварталы Рима – это понятие обширное, **а главное**, что (оно) непредсказуемое.*